# Как добавить подстраницы поста Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, post

Заранее прошу прощения за возможно криво заданный вопрос.

На моем сайте публикуются посты различных обзоров. Как добавить каждому посту подстраницы? Или нечто похожее на страница вложения (как для медиа файлов)

Наглядно:

```
testdomain.com/postlink/

testdomain.com/postlink/detail

testdomain.com/postlink/picture

testdomain.com/postlink/links
```

и тп.

Содержимое подстраниц разумеется уникальное для каждого поста и в идеале должно задаваться в рамках самого поста. Есть мысль выводить все сразу в табах в главном посте, а открывать после перехода на подстраницу, но вот как их организовать и возник вопрос к знающим.

Возможно есть варинт добавить такие "каталоги" посту, а я уже через JS смотрел бы окончание ссылки и открывал тот или иной таб.

Comment: https://wp2.ru/chto-takoe-dochernie-stranicy-i-kak-ih-sozdavat-v-wordpress/

Answer (score 1):

`get_queried_object_id` получает id текущего поста/термина.

Чтобы получить подстраницы используйте параметр `post_parent`:

```
$childs = get_post( [
    'post_type'      => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_parent'    => get_queried_object_id()
] );
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]